# Solve the equation x(132)=(13) in $S_3$

Tags: abstract-algebra

I was absent due to flooding in my neighbordhood when this was discussed in class. Can someone please give me insight on how to go about solving this?

Solve the equation: $x(132)=(13)$ in $S_3$

Edit: so then $x(132)(123)=(13)(123) $ 
          $\space \space \space \space \space$      $x=(12)$.

Comment: Multiply both sides of the equation on the right by the inverse of the $3-$cycle $(1~3~2)$.

Comment: @RobertShore I edited the question to show some work. Does that seem right?

Comment: your work does not seem right; you were supposed to multiply by the *inverse* of $(132)$;  also, $(213)$ is the same permutation as $(132)$

Comment: Which is the inverse of $(132)$? Note that $(213)=(132)$, so does this value verify the given equation? Also, let us compute explicitly, $(13)(132)$ in a point among $1,2,3$. We have $(13)(132) \text{ in } 1=(13)\text{ in } 3=1$. (Sometimes, people define composition of permutations in the other way, inverting the order in the composition of the corresponding functions. But also in this case, if we compose an even and and odd permutation, we get an odd permutation. The sign is a morphism, use it to check computations.)

Comment: It's wrong because $(1~3~2)^{-1} \neq (1~3~2).$

Comment: I'm still confused, maybe I'm not understading how to find the inverse then. The multiplying I feel like I know.

Answer (score 0):

By right multiplication with inverse of (123), $x=(1 3)(123)^{-1}$